# create intersection points between lists of functions

Tags: list, intersection, geogebra

I am trying to find the intersection points between two lists of funtions in geogebra.

Let's say I have the folowing two lists of functions:

```
offset = {1,2}
l1 = x + offset
l2 = -x - offset
```

Now I want to create a list of intersection points of `l1` and `l2`.
Just using `intersect(l1,l2)` doesn't work. I tried declaring it as a list with brackets `{}`, but that doesn't succeed either.

Then I tried defining a seperate index list `index = {1,2}` and using this to clarify which element of the list I want to access `intersect(l1(index),l2(index))`, buuut an *undefined* just kept showing up.

I am grateful for any suggestions.